# Do we need to strain or filter user queries in Mongoose for security purposes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As a long time web dev, my usual answer to everything is use RegEx checking to strain user input. When I'm looking at Mongoose queries, my gut is telling me I don't necessarily have to strain the input, assuming a length check maybe.

This is assuming the express framework has already filtered down the input to either req.body or req.query.

For example, a typical query could be like so in Mongoose:

```
User.findOne({ username : req.query.username }, function(err, doc) {
  // code
});
```

**Is it possible to inject bad things into this specific query?** I would expect yes as it seems hackers always employ very clever things, but would like to see some examples of this. I ask this because this is different than other ways of doing this in terms of not doing string concatination, rather using an object that is already a string or undefined. Thanks!

Please move this if its off topic and I apologize in advance as I was not sure where to ask this.

Answer (score 2):

It's safe when `req.query.username` is a value that you expect (like a string). It won't try to evaluate any JSON inside of it. In case `req.query.username` is an `Object` like e.g. `{ '$exists': true }` it will be evaluated and return unexpected documents.

Your findOne example is fairly 'safe' because you would err on validating the password. With other queries like .remove() it's much more dangerous.

```
var param = { '$exists': true };

User.remove({ username : param }, function (err, affected) {
    console.log(err)
    console.log(affected)
});
```

This would delete all the users in the collection:

Does that help?

---

Edit:

There are similar issues when working with [PHP and Mongo](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.security.php). Much of it would depends on the express framework not creating objects from input parameters.

Comment: +1 This is what I was thinking. I'm still hoping someone will come along and show me some exploit I didn't realize though using my direct example. I'll check you off if that doesn't happen in a couple of days, Justin.